# How to make a line crawl across the screen in Python?

Tags: python, animation, printing

```
print('Loading Documents...')
LoadDocuments() #Function That Loads the Documents
for i in range(0, 30, 1):
    print("-", end="")
    time.sleep(0.1)
print(" ")
print('Documents Loaded')
```

What I want it to do is print  `Loading Documents...` then have an animation of a line crawling across the screen

Instead it prints `Loading Documents` and then after a couple seconds, all the dashes in the line pop up at once

Any Ideas?

Comment: my initial reaction was that it might have something to do with buffering the output. But even running with `python -u` didn't change the behavior....

Comment: @Gil: As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) explain, `-u` will only "Force the binary I/O layers of  stdout and stderr to be unbuffered… The text I/O layer will still be line-buffered…"

Comment: @Gil: You can use `-u` and then wrap a different `TextIOWrapper` around `sys.stdout.buffer` and reassign `sys.stdout` to that, but if you're going to do that, you might as well just rewrap the `sys.stdout.buffer.raw` instead and not bother with the flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Output is normally line-buffered, meaning when you `print` part of a line, it may not get displayed until you finish `print`ing the rest of the line.

You can change the buffering, but the simpler solution is just to explicitly call [`flush`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) on the [`stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) stream (which `print` normally prints to) every time you want to force it to display what you have so far:

```
print('Loading Documents...')
LoadDocuments() #Function That Loads the Documents
for i in range(0, 30, 1):
    print("-", end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
print(" ")
print('Documents Loaded')
```

In this case, it may also be cleaner to also use [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) directly on `stdout`, just to make it clear that you're doing low-level I/O instead of the normal high-level `print` mechanism:

```
print('Loading Documents...')
LoadDocuments() #Function That Loads the Documents
for i in range(0, 30, 1):
    sys.stdout.write('-')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
print(" ")
print('Documents Loaded')
```

---

This is explained in the docs… but only if you know where to look, and already understand most of it…

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) explains that `sys.stdout` is the default file that gets printed to, then [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) says:

> These streams are regular [*text files*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-text-file) like those returned by the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function. Their parameters are chosen as follows: … When interactive, standard streams are line-buffered … You can override this value with the [*-u*](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) command-line option.

If you follow the link to `-u`, it says:

> Force the binary layer of the `stdout` and `stderr` streams (which is available as their `buffer` attribute) to be unbuffered. The text I/O layer will still be line-buffered if writing to the console…

Then you have to follow a few links from `open` or *text files* to get to [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) and read almost the entire module documentation to figure out how to access and rewrap `sys.stdout.buffer.raw` or just call `sys.stdout.flush`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why disabling buffering when calling the code i.e. using `python -u` doesn't give the same result as your solution?

Comment: Apologies, just had my question answered in original comment.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are wanting to display some kind of "progress" to your user.

I recommend you use something like [progress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress)

**Example:**

```
from progress.bar import Bar

bar = Bar('Processing', max=20)
for i in range(20):
    # Do some work
    bar.next()
bar.finish()
```

You do have to install this 3rd-party package hwoever as it's not part of the standard library. Typically this as as simple as:

```
pip install progress
```

Comment: I tried that, I couldn't import `progress bar` I looked up progressbar python and It looks like it is not part of python3, but thanks tho!

Comment: You would have to install it. ``pip install progress``